# Embed credentials in Yammer.com api

Tags: api, yammer

I want to use an external software Alteryx to access the api so I can crawl some JSON data. When I call https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json, it keeps on popping "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbbiden".

I guess there is something wrong with the authentication. Does anybody know how to embed the credentials in the URL? Or is there any other ways to authenticate so an external software can access?

I can do it perfectly with normal browser after logged in.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yammer's Rest API for retrieving data implements OAUTH 2.0.  This is because any application trying to access the data is making the request as an "App" which will then have access to a user's specific data.

Yammer's OAUTH flow is decribed here:  https://developer.yammer.com/docs/oauth-2

I do not yet know of an easy way to implement the authentication using anything other than development within a browser for this process.

You may be better off exporting the json messages to a file and then importing into your external software.